# Multiple sub setting by position, put result in a list

Tags: r

I have a heavy file, which I read in R line by line using readLines, resulting in a very long vector of strings.

Based on the presence of special words in the strings I want to subset the vector into multiple parts, and put all the subsets in a list. This is easily done with a loop. Is there a more efficient way of achieving this? I have been googling for a while, but didn't find anything similar. Maybe I am not using the right keywords.

```
vector_of_strings <- sample(LETTERS, size = 1000, replace = T  )
vector_of_strings[1:15]
[1] "G" "C" "M" "I" "E" "S" "C" "Z" "X" "D" "W" "N" "V" "B" "K"

# get position of the special string
position <- grep("A",vector_of_strings)

# does what i want, but it is very slow for large vectors
my_list <- list()
for(i in 1:(length(position)-1)){
    my_list[[i]] <- vector_of_strings[ position[i] : position[i+1]  ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with given OPs example:

1. Collapse vector
2. Split vector by *pattern*
3. Remove first and last split
4. Add patter to a string and split it back to original form

code:

```
foo <- paste(vector_of_strings, collapse = "")
bar <- strsplit(foo, "A")[[1]]
strsplit(paste0("A", bar[-c(1, length(bar))], "A"), "")
```

Comment: turns out my example wasnt perfect, as strings can have multiple characters. See answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(1234)
vector_of_strings <- paste0( sample(LETTERS, size = 10000, replace = T  ),
                         sample(LETTERS, size = 10000, replace = T  ),
                         sample(LETTERS, size = 10000, replace = T  )
                        )
l <- paste0(vector_of_strings, collapse = "SplitMeHere") 
gg <- strsplit(l, "AAA")[[1]] 
l <- lapply(gg, function(x){strsplit(x, "SplitMeHere")})
```